# Login loop when trying Awesome with Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, session, awesome, gdm

I am trying to use the Awesome window manager with Gnome 3.16 in Ubuntu 16.04. Doing this is documented in several places:

https://scaron.info/blog/awesome-with-gnome-on-ubuntu-14.04.html, https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome, https://makandracards.com/makandra/1367-running-the-awesome-window-manager-within-gnome.

However, I get stuck in a login loop when I try to login with the Awesome GNOME session. The screen will go black briefly and then bring me right back to the login screen. I can login with just GNOME and just Awesome with no problems, but logging into the custom session using both does not work. Here are my files to create the session:

```
/usr/share/xsessions/awesome-gnome.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Awesome GNOME
Comment=Dynamic window manager
Exec=gnome-session --session=awesome
TryExec=awesome
Type=Application


/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/awesome.session
[Gnome Session]
Name=Awesome session
RequiredComponents=awesome;gnome-settings-daemon;
DesktopName=Awesome

/usr/share/applications/awesome.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Awesome
Comment=The awesome launcher!
Exec=awesome
```

I don't see anything wrong. In fact, these files work just fine on my laptop. The only difference I see is that my laptop is running Ubuntu 14.04 rather than 16.04.

When I googled this, most of the solutions were specific to LightDM. When I try to run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

It successfully runs, but I see no change.

Some other solutions involved chown on the ~/.xauthority file, but I don't even that have file on my system.

If anyone could help me out with this I would be very grateful. Let me know if I should post any other information/output.